«Не порядочный»: слитно или раздельно?

Он беспокоит меня уже 40 лет. Он не порядочный человек. Он диктатор.



В словаре есть оба слова:

НЕПОРЯДОЧНЫЙ. Способный на бесчестные, низкие поступки. ПОРЯДОЧНЫЙ. Честный и благородный, ведущий себя в соответствии с принятыми в обществе нормами поведения; не способный на низкие поступки.
Поэтому возможно как отрицание, так и утверждение: не порядочный человек, порядочный человек.
Примеры: — Куевда жмот, скряга, жадный. Он непорядочный человек. Все с ужасом посмотрят на меня с мыслью: мы думали, что он порядочный человек, а он...

Все зависит от контекста

Он беспокоит меня уже 40 лет. (Я могу наконец сделать вывод.)  Он непорядочный человек. Он диктатор. Это утверждение: Он не порядочный человек, диктатор.
Он беспокоит меня уже 40 лет. (Я считал его порядочным человеком, но ошибся).  Он не порядочный человек. Он диктатор. Это противопоставление: не порядочный человек, а диктатор.

«Это противопоставление: не порядочный человек, а диктатор». В оригинале конструкции не (...), а  (...) нету: там два предложения, если формально. И потом, диктатор может быть вполне порядочным, когда речь идёт о государственном деятеле.

Если обозначено противопоставление, то вопросов нет, написание НЕ раздельное. В других случаях для раздельного письма в контексте должно каким-то образом присутствовать  противоположное мнение, которое отрицается.  // Диктатор как порядочный человек? Сейчас это скорее отрицательная оценка, ведь в большинстве стран  нет неограниченной гос. власти.

А если это перечисление через точку? Ведь не одна фраза — две.

А это неважно, учитывается весь контекст.  Отрицать можно то, что сказано, обозначено, каки-то образом угадывается. А если этого нет, то написание слитное.  Мы тогда не отрицаем, а утверждаем.

Залянул в Корпус: из 10 примеров лишь один, хотя с неясным подтекстом, но в тему (Он не порядочный мужик. Он Доцент). Остальное не подходит: отнюдь не П.; если не П.; разве не П.; не средній и не П.
